# Intrusive list implementation for Java?

Tags: java, list, collections, linked-list

Is there any (well implemented) intrusive double linked list class(es) available for Java? Or should I do my own? Boost has it for C++: http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost/intrusive/list.html.

Intrusive list is a container having (in this case) next and prev pointers within element, so typical list operations like replace and remove can be directly targeted into elementary class instead of container class. There are some certain situations, where intrusive list are the best solution.

I try to give an appropriate example. Let's assume I have linked lists L list1 and L list2 owned by different type of classes X1 and Y2.

class Q (which has nothing to do or doesn't easily get access the interfaces of x1 and Y2 otherwise) needs to do  i) replace, ii) remove operation for element e, which exists always in somewhere, in list1 xor list2 depending on run-time state, but that information is not stored directly anywhere.

With intrussive list Q can just store reference to an element to member element e and it always points the right place.

Otherwise you have to choose from several clearly more complex workarounds one or the other.
- Wrapper class for element e and and additional methods for completing operations i and ii. No.

Basically, the question is still not about the performance but architectural complexity.  This can also be understood as one kind of shared object situation where solution IL avoids the update need for every client Lx and Q.

Please notice I do NOT necessary need compatibility to other standard containers. Just an generic intrusive lsit implementation with an iterating, add, remove and find operations used with unknown element class.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain precisely why the "classical" java.util.LinkedList is not a good enough implementation of LinkedList to you ? And also why, oh why, you would prefer not to implement the Collection interface, when it is sure implementing it makes your collection usable, instead of one more NIY symptom.

Comment: @Riduidel. Also, since Java 1.6, there is an excellent alternative for `LinkedList`, called `ArrayDeque`.

Comment: The main benefit of an intrusive list is that, given an element in the list, it can be removed in constant time. No search is necessary because the `next` and `previous` links are right there in the element. See `iterator_to` in the linked Boost doc. There's also some memory savings because an additional wrapper object isn't required for every entry in the list.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I also try to give an general example.

Let's assume I have linked lists L1 and L2 owned by different type of classes X and Y. class Q needs to do an operation to element e, which exists always in other L1 xor L2 depending on run-time state, but no-one knows directly which one.

With intrussive list Q can just store "a pointer" to member element e and it always points the right place.

Comment: ...and that operation I mean typically replace operation.

Comment: One important thing is also that with LinkedList and ArrayList you need two variables: collection (L1 or L2) and that element e, but with intrussive list you be fine with one. This also increases complexity significantly if you need to store a some set of those "pointers" for later use and keep those pairs together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing implementations (and no, I don't consider the normal Java collections  to be intrusive).

That's probably because the only major advantage such a list would have in Java would be the fast `remove()` call when you already have the Element to be removed at hand (and don't have an `Iterator` at that position). The not-copying-the-element is not a valid argument in Java, since Java `List` implementations handle only references anyway (and never copy the whole object).

But you can easily write a general-purpose `List` implementation that is intrusive by creating the necessary interface:

```
public interface IntrusiveListElement<E extends<IntrusiveListElement<E>> {
  public void setNext(E next);
  public E getNext();
  public void setPrev(E prev);
  public E getPrev();
}

public class IntrusiveList<E extends IntrusiveListElement<E>> implements List<E> {
  // implement your run-of-the-mill double-linked list here
}
```

Your element class could look like this:

```
public class MyBusinessElement implements IntrusiveListElement<MyBusinessElement> {
  private MyBusinessElement prev;
  private MyBusinessElement next;

  public void setNext(MyBusinessElement next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

      public MyBusinessElement getNext() {
    return next;
  }

  public void setPrev(MyBusinessElement prev) {
    this.prev = prev;
  }

  public MyBusinessElement getPrev() {
    return prev;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the right answer, eventhough it was I suspected before posting. But its always comfortable when someone has same opinion. ;)

Answer (score 5):

> ***Is there any (well implemented) intrusive double linked list class(es) available for Java?***

I don't believe you'll find one.

My understanding of ***"intrusive"*** is that ***the application object to be stored in the data structure needs to directly include ("intrude") the next/prev pointers within the application object***.

This is in contrast the "pointer wrapper" approach where the data structure node contains a pointer to the application object, thus requiring no modification to application object.  The intrusive approach has [a number of benefits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/intrusive/usage_when.html) including avoiding the double-dereferencing (once for the node and once for the node's pointer to the application object) common to the "pointer wrapper" approach.

I don't believe you'll find an intrusive data structure library for Java.  Java lacks C++-like templates nor multiple inheritance, and it does not easily support copy-by-value of an entire object. Because of this, I don't think there's a way to generically add the next/prev instance fields to a Java object.

For example, given the application object:

```
class Foo {
    int bar;
}
```

somehow you need to be able to add next/prev fields and list management methods to it or a derivative of it:

```
class Foo2 {
    int bar;
    Foo2 prev;
    Foo2 next;
}
```

One way to add these fields by providing a base class with these fields for these application classes to extend - this is Boost's approach.  However, this approach is very limiting in a single-inheritance language like Java.

Java interfaces are often Java's answer to multiple inheritance, e.g. an interface to require getNext() and getPrev() methods of application classes.  However, if you need intrusive data structures for performance reasons, accessing next/prev fields through a method may adversely affect those goals.

Java generics also don't extend classes in needed way.

> ***Or should I do my own?***

If its one time for a specific case for a carefully evaluated need, sure - roll your own.  If you're trying to roll a generic one for general purpose use, I'm not sure its worth it.

One really gross approach would be to custom extend the application class to add the needed fields:

```
class Foo3 extends Foo {
    Foo3 prev;
    Foo3 next;
}
```

and use cut-n-paste reuse to add the list management methods.  I would however strongly recommend ***not*** using this approach.

***Soapbox***

You don't state why you need an intrusive data structure.  Perhaps you have valid reasons for needing one, but its hard to imagine them.  Java is heavily reliant on using object pointers and trying to avoid them like this would be difficult.

I respectfully suggest you consider:

- are you trying to prematurely optimize,
- are you adding unnecessary complexity for little benefit
- if speed and memory management are paramount, are you using the right language?

Answer (score 1):

if you look to SDK code you will see that LinkedList is, in fact, a list of a private class Entry which contains next and previous elements.
So, if you include MyClass in this list, an element of the list will be an Entry with your object and the links for the next and previous elements of the list.

So, i think it is intrusive...

```
private static class Entry<E> {
    E element;
    Entry<E> next;
    Entry<E> previous;

    Entry(E element, Entry<E> next, Entry<E> previous) {
        this.element = element;
        this.next = next;
        this.previous = previous;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not intrusive. An intrusive list has the next/prev pointers in the element itself, so no `Entry` class is used at all.

Answer (score 0):

What do you hope to gain by using an intrusive list? I'm hard pressed to think what the advantages would be. Okay, there's a trivial efficiency that you have just one object instead of two for each node. But the price of this is a big loss in flexibility and reliability. For example, now you can't have the same object in two lists at the same time. What happens if a caller retrieves an instance of a list member and tries to change one of the pointers itself? What it a caller clones a node and fails to update the pointers? Etc.

Dave Ray makes the point that with an intrusive list you can delete a node in constant time because you already have the pointers and don't need to re-find the item. True, but that assumes that you've saved a handle to the node somewhere and are now coming back to it. With the Java LinkedList class pretty much the only way to access elements is to traverse the list with an Iterator, or to search for a particular object. If you traverse with an Iterator, the Iterator.remove will remove in constant time. So it's only if you search, find, and then decide to remove that you pay this penalty. I think it would be an improvement on the LinkedList implementation if they cached a pointer to the last object found to improve the performance on precisely this point. My guess is that they didn't because it would make the remove non-deterministic: You could have the same object in the list multiple times -- either literally the same instance or two objects that compare equal -- and the contract on remove presently says that it always removes the first occurrence. If there was a cached pointer, it would be difficult to say whether this was the first, second, or 42nd.

Oh, to actually answer your question: No, I'm not aware of an open-source implementation out there. But then if I needed my own flavor of a linked list, I think I'd just roll my own. Presumably if the standard Java one doesn't meet your needs, that must mean that you have some pretty specialized need. In which case searching for an off-the-shelf implementation that happens to meet your specialized need sounds like a lot of trouble, and you could surely implement it in, what, a day or two of work? You'd probably spend more time searching for a suitable product than it would take to just do it. You've probably already spent more time reading the replies to this post than it would have taken you to write it.

Comment: "If you traverse with an Iterator, the Iterator.remove will remove in constant time." This is misleading. Traversing with an iterator to find an object is linear. The actual removal of the element is constant only for LinkedLists, but linear for ArrayLists (due to having to shift all the elements to the right of the removed element in the backing array).

Comment: @DhruvGairola Yes, when I said that iterator.remove takes constant time, I was speaking within the context of discussing linked lists, not arrays or any other structure. And yes, FINDING an object, as opposed to the remove itself, is linear. Sorry if I mislead anyone on that. Finding an object in a linked list is ... well, let's say I can't think of any way you could make it faster than linear without turning it into a more complex structure that is not what we normally think of when we say "linked list".

Answer (score -1):

Have you taken a look at the [Deque class](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html)?  Per the javadoc, "A linear collection that supports element insertion and removal at both ends. The name deque is short for "double ended queue" and is usually pronounced "deck"."
It is implemented by [ArrayDeque](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html), [LinkedBlockingDeque](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) and [LinkedList](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Answer (score -1):

Java's semantics are by design intrusive, they use references and don't copy. You basically just want to find the best linked list implementation that java has, [LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) or whatever, and it'll be intrusive.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Foo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] i = new String[1];
    i[0] = "FOO";
    String[] j = new String[1];
    j[0] = "BAZ";

    LinkedList<String[]> list = new LinkedList<String[]>();

    list.add(i);
    list.add(j);

    for (String[] x: list) {
      System.out.println(x[0]);
    }

    i[0] = "ZILCH";

    for (String[] x: list) {
      System.out.println(x[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the output, notice how changing i changed the value in the list.

```
FOO
BAZ
ZILCH
BAZ
```