# List impl which does no allocations

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Do you know of a java.util.List-like implementation which never allocates objects for the .add(T) method? I know of [HugeCollections](https://code.google.com/p/vanilla-java/source/browse/#svn/trunk/collections/src/main/java/vanilla/java/collections/impl) which stores objects in direct memory, but it still allocates objects on the heap to resize.

I realize it's a strange request. It's a one-off use case, building a heap-aware tool.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you require? A collection, that offloads everything to unmanaged memory? An ArrayList for example will not create objects on `add(T)`, unless it is resizing. You could also write a List implementation, which uses a single fixed size array - that would have deterministic memory requirements (it is static), and allocating a single array increases the chance to get a contigous piece of heap for it.

Comment: To me this looks like you are trying to profile a pice of code and do the book keeping in the same JVM. If yes you are probably better off using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html or JProfiler.

Comment: You can use `Arrays.asList` to get a simple list wrapper around a pre-sized array.  You won't be able to add to it, because its size will always be the size of the backing array, but you can set elements.

Comment: You are right, if I don't need to resize it's easier. But I need to allow resizing. Banana (see Omry's answer) could probably be extended with a direct memory allocator which _should_ then work.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Banana](https://github.com/omry/banana), my open source primitive collections library.
The list API there is not identical to java.util.List, but it does offer a linked list which does not allocate memory when you add an item to the list.
Check the project wiki for more info.

Comment: Banana's LinkedList#appendTail causes `new int[]` to be called through `net.yadan.banana.memory.block.BlockAllocator#increaseSize`. Have you experimented with a direct memory `IBlockAllocator` implementation? Seems like a natural extension to the lib and would then serve my need. Thanks.

Comment: increaseSize is not normally called, only when the underlying storage runs out of memory. and even when it is called it's not called per object you are adding so the overhead is creates is small. in addition, you can tune your initial storage size so a resize will not be needed.

direct memory (Unsafe) is something I plan to play with but didn't yet.

Answer (score 1):

As comments have suggested, a fixed-size [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [`Arrays::asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) is a simple and efficient option if you can tolerate a fixed-size list.

If you need an arbitrarily growable list, then things are more complicated. If you have control over the objects you're storing, then you could use an [intrusive container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/intrusive/intrusive_vs_nontrusive.html). I am not aware of any canned implementations of intrusive containers for Java, but you could look at [Joachim Sauer's answer outlining how to write one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3727636/116639). Essentially, it's a completely normal linked list, but the objects you store provide the link fields, so you don't need to allocate any additional storage to add them to the list. There are some other advantages too, like being able to remove an object in O(1) time if you have the actual object already. There are some disadvantages as well, of course.

Comment: Because creating the intrusive element wrapper would require an allocation it doesn't work for me. Unless, that wrapper was allocated off heap in which case this works. Maybe there is such an implementation floating around, a direct memory intrusive list.

Comment: No, the point is that in an intrusive container, the things you are adding hold the link pointers. There is zero allocation when you add to an intrusive container. However, you can only do that if you control the classes of the objects you're adding, so you can add the pointer fields. If you don't, then you can't use an intrusive collection. You could put an intrudable wrapper around the elements you want to add, but then you've just got a normal non-intrusive linked list!

Comment: Gotcha. Then I can't use an intrusive container.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to override the add method to stop it growing:

```
public class FixedArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    private final int size;
    public FixedArrayList(int size) {
        super(size);
        this.size = size;
    }
    public void add(T t) {
        if (size() == size) {
            // throw exception or do nothing
        }
        super.add(t);
    }
}
```

You could override `addAll()` too if you want.

Comment: if you will check the implementation of ArrayList, you will see that it's allocating a object for each item you put into the list.